React TS, return prevMinutes - 1; execute 2 times
    import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function Timer() {
  const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState<number>(5);
  const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState<number>(3);
  const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState<number>(1);
  const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState<number>(1);
  const [timerWork, setTimerWork] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const intervalRef = useRef<number | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timerWork) {
      const updateTime = () => {
        console.log(123);
        setTimerSeconds((prevSeconds) => {
          if (prevSeconds === 0) {
            setTimerMinutes((prevMinutes) => {
              if (prevMinutes === 0) {
                setTimerHours((prevHours) => {
                  if (prevHours === 0) {
                    setTimerDays((prevDays) => {
                      if (prevDays === 0) {
                        alert("The end");
                      }
                      return prevDays - 1;
                    });
                    return 23;
                  }
                  return prevHours - 1;
                });
                return 59;
              }
              console.log(-1);
              return prevMinutes - 1;
            });
            return 59;
          }
          return prevSeconds - 1;
        });
      };
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [timerWork]);

  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <h1>
        Simple timer with useState, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useCallback.
      </h1>

      <h2>
        <span>Days: {timerDays} |</span>
        <span> Hours: {timerHours} |</span>
        <span> Minutes: {timerMinutes} |</span>
        <span> Seconds: {timerSeconds}</span>
      </h2>

      <button onClick={() => setTimerWork(true)}>Start timer</button>
      <button onClick={() => setTimerWork(false)}>Stop timer</button>
    </div>
  );
}

Here is my Timer.tsx component. My minutes decrease by 2, not by 1, when seconds go to 0. I'm a beginner as React Developer and I can't understand why
console.log(-1); 
return prevMinutes - 1;

execute 2 times.
console.log(-1)
is a evidence, that return prevMinutes - 1;  did 2 times
I did try to change return prevMinutes - 1; to return prevMinutes - 0.5;, this change solved my problem, but I want to understand, why this code execude two times.
